# Set package versions in package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I have a lot of packages as dependencies in `package.json`, but they all have `*` as versions.

I have read that this is unrecommended, so I want to add the latest versions to all of them. How can I do this? I have tried [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates), but it says that all packages are up-to-date.

Comment: ```npm update --save --save-dev``` will install the latest package that maches the ```*``` semver, and will save this version with a caret in your ```package.json```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
npm-check-updates -u
npm install
```

Comment: It doesn't override the `*`, since `*` is also considered the latest version